# Remove @domain.com if user inputs full username into login field

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have a login form for my app and I have two `TextBox` controls; one for username and one for password.

I am wanting to programmatically remove any "@domain.com" that is added to the username. So if they input "user1@domain.com" and click login the "@domain.com" part is removed from the string sent to the webservice.

All users would attempt to use the same domain so I know what they will try to use. If that helps.

My current code is:

```
Dim userInput As String = UserName.Text
Dim index As Integer = userInput.LastIndexOf("@")
If index > 0 Then
    userInput = userInput.Substring(0, index)
    userInput = UserName.Text
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim input As String = "awiles@domain.com"
Dim index As Integer = input.LastIndexOf("@")
If index > 0 Then
   input = input.Substring(0, index)
End If
```

Input will give you "awiles"

Comment: Didn't work still passed at the @domain.com. I posted my code in the question.

Comment: @Bugs Thank you very much that fixed it for me. Appreciate the response. And I apologize for me junior level skills. I am still learning vb and visual studio.

Comment: @JayyCodez it's not a problem, here to help when we can. Consider accepting Tony's answer. There should be a checkbox just under the voting to the left. (I'll also delete my comment, now that you've fixed it. Feel free to do the same)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [String.Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Returns a new string in which all the characters in the current instance, beginning at a specified position and continuing through the last position, have been deleted.

Something like this would do it:

```
If UserName.Text.Contains("@") Then
    UserName.Text = UserName.Text.Remove(UserName.Text.IndexOf("@"))
End If
```

You could also put this into one line if you were so inclined:

```
If UserName.Text.Contains("@") Then UserName.Text = UserName.Text.Remove(UserName.Text.IndexOf("@"))
```